# Ethernet not working suddenly

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am using ubuntu 20.04, till now there is no problem but suddenly my ethernet stopped working when I type 
`sudo lshw -C network`

I posted the same in focal bug section, but they advised me to post it here. So I am reposting it the same.
This is the result

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2200000-a2200fff memory:a2000000-a2003fff
```

But I am able to connect to WiFi.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *focal fossa* hasn't been released yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: What *focal* bug section?    I've yet to see a IRC or telegram ubuntu+1 bug discussion 
 suggest here, and would like the group so I can look up who said it (all discussions are recorded & kept). I suspect you mis-interpreted their instructions.  If you have problems, and for the next few days it's far easier to fix bugs, in contrast to after release where it's easier to fix in the next 20.10 release. As 20.04 is a LTS release, we want to fix bugs for the LTS instead of push to 20.10 if possible, so details should be reported & filed on #ubuntu+1 and #ubuntu-quality.

Comment: File this as a bug against the kernel in Focal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my kernel by going into grub menu (downgraded). That did restore back my ethernet. I don't know why.

Does downgrading effect anything else ?

Comment: Downgrading tends to lend you not getting patches and other fixes.  However, issues with 20.04 such as this need to be filed as bugs against 20.04 - it is not yet on topic here.